# How do I make it so a discord music bot deletes the "Now playing" message after the music ends?

Tags: javascript, bots

That's what my bot uses:

```
"@discordjs/opus": "^0.3.3",
"discord-player": "^3.3.2",
"discord.js": "^12.5.1",
"ffmpeg-static": "^4.2.7"
```

I've tried like this, but it didn't work, also I wanted to make it so when you skip the music it deletes the message too

```
module.exports = (client, message, track) => {
message.channel.send(`${client.emotes.music} - Now playing ${track.title} into ${message.member.voice.channel.name} ...`).then(msg => {
    msg.delete({
        timeout: (track.duration + "000")
    });
});
};
```

Any ideas how can I do it?  UwU

Comment: please include the dependencies as text in your post instead of a screenshot on an external image hosting website, help us help you

Comment: also, try and indent your code so that it's easy to read. You can use something like https://beautifier.io/ Nobody likes scrolling horizontal code

Answer (score 0):

I am using the following code which I got partially from [discordjs.guide](https://discordjs.guide/voice/the-basics.html#playing-audio).

I created an songQueue variable where I store all my data.

```js
const songQueue = {
    textChannel: null,
    voiceChannel: null,
    connection: null,
    songs: [],
    volume: 10,
    playing: true,
    loop: 'disabled',
    nowPlayingMessage: null,
};
```

When an song ends it deletes the *Now Playing* message.

```js
dispatcher.on('finish', () => {
   songQueue.nowPlayingMessage.delete();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
const time = track.duration * 1000
message.channel.send('your-message').then(m => setTimeout({
       m.delete
   }, time)
)
```

This is what i use!
It deletes the message after the music ended